# How can I tie an alert to a LIbra database?

Tags: libreoffice, database

I want to know how to tie an "alert" or notification to a column in a LibreOffice database table.

I'm a new Linux user and am working with a LibreOffice database. In the near future I intend to put together a database of my clients. Could anybody tell me if it would be possible to work some sort of alert tied to a date in each entry, for example if the database records mr J.Smith having work done on the 15/01/2014 can I get base to remind me to call him a month later?

Comment: I would think this question would be better received if posted in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I don't know of LibreOffice supports stored procedures, but you are almost better writing an external script to query the database's table on a regular basis looking for something that happened a month ago, and then performing some action based on that. You probably would need another table denoting the action your script took, so that action would not be duplicated.

Comment: Do you mean [LibreOffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/)?

Comment: Consider asking this on the Ask LibreOffice site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would get better help via an Libra Office Forum. However, you can use a query to tie the entry date to a call back date.

> select  Year(`date`) || '-' || Month(`date`) + 1 || '-' || Day(`date`) AS "+1 month" from Table1

HSQL included in base doesn't support dateadd yet (or any date math that I can find), but it's going to be in the next version.

Please note the code above will fail for an entire month, it's just an idea and not a final answer. Of course if your backed with MySQL or something else then you can do some proper date math.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simplistic but it works for my client database as I'm in it *daily* (LibreOffice Base):  I have a 'next_date' date field which I search daily. I also search all entries before today's date to see if I've missed any.